# How to get nth Higest value from table in mysql

Tags: mysql

I want to know that How to get nth Higest value from table in mysql
Please give me a simple query

Comment: You can use `max()` funtion to find the highest value.

Comment: @Ehsan `max()` returns the highest value, but OP is looking for _n_ th highest value.

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself?

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT expectedValue
FROM fooTable
ORDER BY expectedValue
LIMIT n-1,1
```

where n is your `nth` value (`n-1` as is zero indexed)

Look at this sql fiddle for retrieve 5th higher value: [example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d552b/1)

Comment: Order by ASC ? Not needed ?

Comment: @2-Stroker: DESC but is default

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT(your_value) FROM table ORDER BY your_column DESC LIMIT n-1,1
```